# Sample data based on histogram bins

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I have data showing different properties and their sizes in terms of total units and whether or not they have cable. I want to take a sample of the data so that each bin of the histogram has the same number of observations based on `cable ind`.

```
import seaborn as sns

# Data
data = {
    'size': [10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 30, 30, 40, 40, 50, 50, 60, 60, 60],
    'cable_ind': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0]
}

# Creating histogram with hue
sns.histplot(data=data, x='size', hue='cable_ind', bins=[10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70], alpha = .5)

# Displaying the histogram
plt.show()
```

Produces this histogram:

[image]

Basically, I want to sample the data so that each bin above has equal number of `cable_ind = 0` and `cable_ind = 1`.

EDIT: Also the real dataset I am working with is about 50,000 records.

EDIT: EDIT: Code was wrong, re-wrote and reproduced the plot.

Comment: So, you're saying that the `cable_ind` is irrelevant, right?  So, why not just assign the value alternatively?  If the last thing you put in bin 10-20 was a 0, then the next one should be a 1.  And the only column that's off here is the first one.  The rest are already balanced.

Comment: Alternatively, just sort the points into the appropriate bins separated by `cable_ind`, find the longer of the two, and delete points from the other.

Comment: @TimRoberts I may have screwed up the plot but the cable_ind is essential. If the first bin has 6 with no cable and 1 with cable then I would want the sample from that bin to show 1 with cable, 1 without. If the 2nd bin 10-20 shows 5 without cable and 4 with cable then I would want that bin to show 4 with cable and 4 without.

Comment: I'd like every bin, if possible, to have the same number of cable = 0 and cable = 1 records. EDIT: and I'd like to accomplish this without synthetic data.

Comment: But you don't have  5 and 4; what you produced was a STACKED plot.  The 20 bin has 4 of cable 1 and 1 of cable 0.

Comment: @TimRoberts I screwed up the plot and code. Just edited it - regardless, I'm looking to have each bin with equal number of cable 1 and cable 0. So the 20 bin would get cable 1 down-sampled  to be equal to the number of cable 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could [`cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) to form bins, then compute a [`crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) of the cable_ind and bins and get the [`min`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.min.html) per bin. Finally shuffle the dataframe with [`sample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html) and get up to the number of possible values with [`cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumcount.html):

```
data = {
    'size': [10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 30, 30, 40, 40, 50, 50, 60, 60, 60],
    'cable_ind': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# compute bins
bin_s = pd.cut(df['size'], bins=[10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70], right=False)

# compute crosstab, determine the max number of items to keep per bin
keep = pd.crosstab(df['cable_ind'], bin_s).min()

# shuffle (optional), get up to the max number of common items per bin
out = df[df.sample(frac=1) # only if you want a random sampling
           .groupby(['cable_ind', bin_s])
           .cumcount().lt(bin_s.map(keep))]
```

Example output (with `bin_s` as column for clarity):

```
    size  cable_ind     bin_s
0     10          0  [10, 20)
6     10          1  [10, 20)
7     20          1  [20, 30)
8     20          0  [20, 30)
12    30          1  [30, 40)
13    30          0  [30, 40)
16    50          1  [50, 60)
17    50          0  [50, 60)
19    60          1  [60, 70)
20    60          0  [60, 70)
```

Graph of the output:

```
sns.histplot(data=out, x='size', hue='cable_ind',
             bins=[10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70],
             multiple='stack', edgecolor='black')
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This does what you asked, although I'm not sure how useful the results are.  In your sample data, one of the two cable_ind values always has one element, so you end up with one of each:

```
# Data
data = {
    'size': [10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 30, 30, 40, 40, 50, 50, 60, 60, 60],
    'cable_ind': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0]
}

# Make bins by tens.

bins = [([],[]) for _ in range(len(data['size']))]
for s,ci in zip(data['size'],data['cable_ind']):
    bin = s//10
    bins[bin][ci].append( s )

print(bins)
newdata = {'size':[], 'cable_ind':[]}
for a0,a1 in bins:
    if not a1:
        continue
    l = min(len(a0),len(a1))
    newdata['size'].extend(a0[:l])
    newdata['cable_ind'].extend([0]*l)
    newdata['size'].extend(a1[:l])
    newdata['cable_ind'].extend([1]*l)

print(newdata)
```

Output:

```
[([], []), ([10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10], [10]), ([20], [20, 20, 20, 20]), ([30], [30]), ([], [40, 40]), ([50], [50]), ([60], [60, 60]), ([], []), ([], []), ([], []), ([], []), ([], []), ([], []), ([], []), ([], []), ([], []), ([], []), ([], []), ([], []), ([], []), ([], [])]
{'size': [10, 10, 20, 20, 30, 30, 50, 50, 60, 60], 'cable_ind': [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]}
```

They're clearly all balanced now.